# How to parse rss in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rss

How should I go about parsing rss feeds in a rails 3.1 app.  Having trouble finding current resources on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need this in your controller:

```
require 'rss'
rss = RSS::Parser.parse(open('http://example.com/feed/posts').read, false)
```

From [Parsing an RSS feed with Ruby](http://travisonrails.com/2007/06/09/parsing-an-rss-feed-with-ruby).